# Need help categorizing keywords and concepts for two different scenarios

Tags: homework, processor, thread

I am currently working on a project that involves categorizing certain keywords and concepts into two different scenarios. I am having a bit of trouble determining which scenario each keyword belongs to. I was hoping someone with more experience could offer some insight.

The keywords and concepts I need to categorize are: SIMD, MIMD, hardware multithreading, VLIW, false sharing, Advanced Vector Extension (AVX), Message Passing Interface (MPI), and dynamic multiple issue.

The two scenarios are as follows:

Scenario #1: A computer with a shared memory superscalar multicore (8 cores) processor with simultaneous multithreading (SMT). The processor has separated L1 caches and a shared L2 cache. The computer uses a modern Linux operating system.

Scenario #2: A high-performance cluster system with 1000 computers connected by an Ethernet network. Each computer has an uniprocessor with static multiple issue and data-level parallelism at the instruction level. The processors have separated instruction and data caches. The cluster has software for massive big data computations.

Here is my attempt at categorizing the keywords and concepts:

Scenario #1:

- SIMD
- Hardware multithreading
- False sharing
- Advanced Vector Extension (AVX)
- Dynamic multiple issue

Scenario #2:

- MIMD
- VLIW
- Message Passing Interface (MPI)

I would greatly appreciate any feedback or suggestions on my categorization. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola Yeah! I study in Uni.